# Rename strings with identical names

Tags: r, string, data-cleaning, stringr

## Context

When importing columns with identical names from a spreadsheet software, readxl transform doublons with the following syntax : "Col1","Col1" becomes : "Col1","Col1...2". I would like instead to transform it into "Col1","Col1A".

Here is a reproducible example :

## Example

```
# Original string : 
library(stringr)
string <- c("G01","G01...2","G02","G03","G04","G04...6","G05","G05...8")
# Desired result
result <- c("G01","G01A","G02","G03","G04","G04A","G05","G05A")
# this line successfully detects the wrongful entries : 


str_detect(string,pattern = "[:alpha:][:digit:][:digit:]...[:digit:]")
 # this line fails to address the issue correctly : 
 str_replace(string,"[:alpha:][:digit:][:digit:]...[:digit:]", "[:alpha:][:digit:][:digit:]A")
    #output : 
    [1] "G01"                          "[:alpha:][:digit:][:digit:]A" "G02"                         
    [4] "G03"                          "G04"                          "[:alpha:][:digit:][:digit:]A"
    [7] "G05"                          "[:alpha:][:digit:][:digit:]A"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `str_remove` to remove the substring that start with one or more `.` followed by any other characters and then use `make.unique` to change the duplicates by appending `.1`, `.2` etc

```
library(stringr)
make.unique(str_remove(string, "\\.+.*"))
```

---

If we need to add `LETTERS`, the issue would be that there will be only 26 duplicates that can be filled

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there will not be more than 26 duplicates, you could do

```
nm = sapply(strsplit(string, "\\.{3}"), function(x) x[1])
paste0(nm, ave(nm, nm, FUN = function(x) c("", LETTERS)[seq_along(x)]))
# [1] "G01"  "G01A" "G02"  "G03"  "G04"  "G04A" "G05"  "G05A"
```